# type error: sigmoid() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scope'

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tensorflow incpetion_v3 network for feature extraction. I got the following error:

```
   _, end_points = inception_v3.inception_v3(images, is_training=False, num_classes=1001)
  File "/home/osman/viennaclassification/models/slim/nets/inception_v3.py", line 525, in inception_v3
    end_points['Predictions'] = prediction_fn(logits, scope='Predictions')
TypeError: sigmoid() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scope'
```

Comment: The default `prediction_fn` looks like it's `slim.softmax`, which is an alias for `tf.contrib.layers.softmax`, which [takes a scope argument in TensorFlow 1.2](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/softmax). Are you using a different `prediction_fn`? Or an older version of TensorFlow/slim?

Comment: You are right. I used different prediction_fn, which causes the problem. After changing to the soft_max, it is fixed. Thanks.